# sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_max: No such file or directory

Tags: networking, centos7, sysctl

I try to change `net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max` by editing /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 65535
```

and sysctl -p

But i receive error:

> sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_max: No such file or directory

CentOS 7

Comment: try 
`net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = xxxx` and
`net.nf_conntrack_max = xxxxx`
instead

Answer (score 16):

Try

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = xxxx
```

and

```
net.nf_conntrack_max = xxxxx
```

instead.

Or maybe `ip_conntrack` is not loaded. Try:

```
lsmod |grep conntrack
```

If this is empty, load it with:

```
modprobe ip_conntrack
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the setting `net.nf_conntrack_max` instead:

```
# sysctl net.nf_conntrack_max
net.nf_conntrack_max = 262144
```

Also `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max`:

```
# sysctl net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 262144
```

(There are various aliases for the same internal value).